# Azure Function Docker image and the dependencies being restored

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, azure-functions

We're building Azure Durable Function that uses Python as the main language. The Docker image we found in GitHub and use now takes .NET Core SDK 3.1 as a base image and restores the 'WebJobs.Script.WebHost' project. The question is, why do we need .NET SDK/Runtime here if the Function is Python-based:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS runtime-image
ARG HOST_VERSION

ENV PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false

RUN BUILD_NUMBER=$(echo ${HOST_VERSION} | cut -d'.' -f 3) && \
    git clone --branch v${HOST_VERSION} https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host /src/azure-functions-host && \
    cd /src/azure-functions-host && \
    HOST_COMMIT=$(git rev-list -1 HEAD) && \
    dotnet publish -v q /p:BuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER /p:CommitHash=$HOST_COMMIT src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobs.Script.WebHost.csproj -c Release --output /azure-functions-host --runtime linux-x64 && \
    mv /azure-functions-host/workers /workers && mkdir /azure-functions-host/workers && \
    rm -rf /root/.local /root/.nuget /src
```

[Link to a GitHub project that contains Docker images for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/3.0/buster/amd64/python/python37/python37.Dockerfile).
The Docker manifest also takes Python later in the manifest and restores its dependencies as it should be. However, it seems like an enormous overhead which results in a container of almost 2Gb in size.

At the same time, whenever I create a project via the CLI (with the Docker image included) it generates a manifest like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Yes, Azure Durable Functions for Python is in preview now. But is this a reason for the huge Docker manifest file with .NET Core and restoring  'WebJobs.Script.WebHost'? What's the fundamental diff between these manifests? Or my understanding is entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions' Runtime is built using C# and is the component that defines the functions, whose metadata is used for scaling on Azure. Also, the runtime is what powers the bindings, logging to app insights, etc.

The second Dockerfile that is generated from the CLI is the one that you would want to use as it already has the functions runtime. You just add your code on top of that for deployment. This way, the layers of the base container would be downloaded just once for all python functions in the same docker host.